# Visa requirement for Ireland

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I intend to visit Ireland for 2/3 days, I have a valid UK visa stamped C Family Visit.
Do I need a visa for Ireland, I will be in the UK before visiting Ireland?

Answer (score 1):

There are some exceptions but in general, no, you don’t need a visa http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Irish%20Short%20Stay%20Visa%20Waiver%20Programme